# Excel concatenate with IF condition

Tags: excel

There are two cells A2 and B2.

If

```
the cell B2 isn't empty, then concatenate A2 and B2 separated by a ','

(A2,B2)
```

else

```
have A2 alone
```

Comment: So, what is your question or the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3):

Put, in any cell,

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), A2, A2 & "," & B2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

`=A2&IF(B2="","",","&B2)`